# Strong or weak convergence of $f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}$ if $x \in [0,n]$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider $$f_n(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} & x \in [0,n] \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}. $$ Does it converge strongly in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$? Or does it have any weakly convergent subsequences?

Comment: What are strong and weak convergences in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 2):

If $g \in C_c (\Bbb {R}) $ is arbitrary, then

> $\int f_n g dx \to 0$.

Hence, the only possible (weak) limit of any subsequence is ???

But

> if we take $g \equiv 1$, then $\int f_n g dx =1$ for all $x $.

Hence, there is no weakly convergent subsequence. In particular, the sequence does not converge strongly.

Comment: Why $\int f_n g dx \to 0$?

Comment: @Riku: You have $\|f_n\|_\infty \leq 1/n $ and hence $|\int f_n g dx| \leq \| f_n\|_\infty \|g\|_1 \to 0$.